# Infinite loop of sequential animation of ImageButton

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm new to android studio and I want to animate an imageButton with a sequential animation set. The animation set (animation_boutons.xml)is in res/anim.
I've tried with animationSet in java but the app crashed every time I launched the emulator.
I've spent a long time looking for a solution. I hope someone can help me !
I apologize if it's something obvious.

java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        configureCodeurBouton();
    }
    private void configureCodeurBouton() {
        ImageButton boutonCodeur = findViewById(R.id.boutoncodeur);
        Animation animBoutons = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim_boutons);
        animBoutons.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        boutonCodeur.setAnimation(animBoutons);
        boutonCodeur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, codeur.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="true"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <rotate

        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="20"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:duration="1000"
        />

    <rotate
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:fromDegrees="20"
        android:toDegrees="-20"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="2000"
        />

    <rotate

        android:fromDegrees="-20"
        android:toDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="3000"
        android:duration="1000"
        />

</set>
```

Also, Vedprakash Wagh give me the advice to try animBoutons.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE) but it has no effect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change the whole xml anim_boutons file so I have only one animation and not three rotate animations. the repeatMode line says to repeat the animation backwards at each repeat. This gives the expected effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="true"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <rotate

        android:fromDegrees="-20"
        android:toDegrees="20"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
    />

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing every time because you're trying to find your ImageButton when the class is created first, and not after the layout is set.

You're getting `NullPointerException`, as there is no ImageButton with id `R.id.boutoncodeur` in your View hierarchy when you're trying to find it.

You need to find your `ImageView` **AFTER** it is available in your View hierarchy i.e. after your `setContentView();`

You can either do this:

1. Remove your second line

   ```
   ImageButton boutonCodeur = findViewById(R.id.boutoncodeur);
   ```

   as you've already found your `ImageView` in your `configureCodeurButton()` function.
2. Or, you can keep one class variable of `ImageView`, and make `findViewById` call after `setContentView` like below.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ImageButton boutonCodeur;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       boutonCodeur = findViewById(R.id.boutoncodeur);
       configureCodeurBouton();
   }
   private void configureCodeurBouton() {
       Animation animBoutons = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim_boutons);
       boutonCodeur.setAnimation(animBoutons);
       boutonCodeur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, codeur.class));
           }
       });
   }
   }
   ```

You can learn more about `NullPointerException` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Also, learn how to read the errors from tutorials that are available. Or, simply open the logcat tab in Android Studio when the error occurs to know what Error you're getting.

2. To make your animation run infinitely, you can add this in your code.

> animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed that on the post and I learned something. However, do you have an idea for my problem ? (make the animation infinite)

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it out. If it helped you, don't forget to mark it as accepted

Comment: No it doesn't work. The animation launches one time and then stops. I tried with another value than Animation.INFINITE too (like 15) to see if the argument was the problem, but it has no effect. I think the fact it is an animation set blocks this method.

Comment: add android:repeatCount="infinite" to all your rotate animations and remove setrepeat count from code

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work as expected. Every rotate animation restarts alone and the full animation is bugged. At least it is infinite. Any other idea ? Also, when I open a new activity and then come back, the bugged animation doesn't work.

Comment: I figured out a solution. It's way simpler. I changed the whole xml file to have only on rotate animation and I set `android:repeatCount="infinite"` and `android:repeatMode="reverse"`. The repeatMode allows me to do the animation backwards and not to have a sequential animation. Thank you for your time and help !